# SubVersion : upgrade from 1.7.4 to 1.8.11 issue with mod_authz_svn

Tags: apache, svn, upgrade

we are using SubVersion since many years, we survided to several upgrades, but now we stuck upgrading our production environment from 1.7.4. to 1.8.11.

After the upgrade, inside the log I found an error message like this:

> Failed to load the mod_authz_svn config: Section name
>   'MyNotWorkingRepository:/Host/' contains non-canonical fspath '/Host/'

I googled a lot without finding any useful information!

The ACL files were not changed during the upgrade and the strange behavior is that someone works despite to others, similar, that don't work!

Here is an excerpt of the working one:

```
[/]
administrator = rw
supervisor = rw

[MyWorkingRepository:/]
developer1 = rw
developer2 = rw

Here is an excerpt of the NOT working one:

[groups]
developers = developer1, developer2

[/]
administrator = rw
supervisor = rw

[MyWorkingNotRepository:/]
developer1 = r
developer2 = r
developer3 = r
developer4 = r

[MyWorkingNotRepository:/Client/]
developer1 = rw
developer2 = rw

[MyWorkingNotRepository:/Host/]
developer3 = rw
developer4 = rw
```

Could you help us or point me to a documentation about ACL parser changes?

Thank you very much,
Antonio Petricca

**Edit 1** : SubVersion is hosted on a Windows Server machine.

Answer (score 3):

Try removing trailing slash from `/Host/` to make it cannonical:

```
/Host
```

I could not find any official docs, but some forums (eg. [this one](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/subversion_users/rJrQZGhQJSQ)) are claiming that [this test](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/subversion/trunk/subversion/tests/libsvn_subr/dirent_uri-test.c?view=markup&pathrev=1037662) (which is returning false on line 2873) indicates that there was change in parsing `authz` file, so paths such as `/a/` are not valid in SVN version 1.8+.